# Pass vector to httr2 req_headers()

Tags: r, tidyverse, httr, httr2

This seems a bit silly but I'm trying to figure out how to pass a vector of headers to req_headers() so a toy code example that works:

```
req <- request("http://example.com")
req %<>% req_headers(myHeader1 = "value1", myHeader2 = "value2)
```

But what I'm trying to do is something like:

```
headerValues <- c(myHeader1 = "value1", myHeader2 = "value2")    
req <- request("http://example.com")
req %<>% req_headers(headerValues)
```

I've tried headerValues as a list too but no luck.

Comment: Where do `request` and `req_headers` come from? They don't seem to be part of `httr`

Comment: @Matt They are a part of [httr2](https://httr2.r-lib.org/), the successor of `httr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax used in `httr2` is consistent with the rest of the "tidyeval" syntax used throughout the tidyverse. If you want to inject named parmaeters into a call, use the `!!!` syntax.

```
headerValues <- c(myHeader1 = "value1", myHeader2 = "value2")    
req %>% req_headers(!!!headerValues)
```

For more details, check out the [rlang guide to injection](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-inject.html).

Comment: Perfect, and thanks for the link.